# How to push data to array from an inner function in an outer function

Tags: javascript

I am writing a Node.js utility for a bigger project that needs access to the file system. I am using the `fs` module for this purpose. Due to the way that `fs` works, I need a ton of nested functions in order to work.

I have an array at the second-highest scope (aka at the top of the function). I read the directory to get all folders/project names, then I loop over them using `forEach`. Now using `fs.readFile`, I read the JSON file that is present in all the directories. I append the data to the array then return the array at then end.

```js
const get_projects = () => {
    let projects = [];

    fs.readdir(projectsPath, (err, files) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        files.forEach(file => {
            fs.readFile(path.join(projectsPath, file, 'project.json'), { encoding: 'utf8'}, (err, data) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                const value = JSON.parse(data || "{}")
                projects = [...projects, value];
            })
        })
    })

    return projects;
}
```

Now, for some reason (I expect it has something to do with scope), the function returns an empty array despite adding the data to the array.

I've tried replacing `Array.push` by adding the value manually (as seen above). I've also tried converting the function to a class to make use of the `this` keyword, using the `fs/promises` library and callbacks (following the steps/instructions in the original question). No luck.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3001761. Use `fs/promises`.

Comment: try the synchronous methods of fs

Comment: @jonrsharpe that didn't fix my problem. I still cannot return `projects`. I tried using a callback, but that also didn't work.

Comment: I ended up fixing this issue by adding an `index.json` file in the root of the projects directory and getting the projects from that file.